# How to validate Azure Virtual machine username and password?

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service

Need to validate the Azure Virtual machine username and password.

Now used the following code to validate the Virtual machine username and password.

```
$SecureVmPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -string $VmPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$VmCredential = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $Fqdn"\"$VmUsername, $SecureVmPassword
Invoke-Command -ConnectionUri $RemoteConnectionUri.ToString() -Credential $VmCredential -ScriptBlock{
}
```

But cannot able to validate the Virtual machine credentials while Virtual machines are in shutdown state.

Is there any way to validate Virtual machine credentials even when the Virtual machines are in shutdown state?

Comment: what kind of question is that? how do you try to connect to a vm that is not running? are you sane?

Comment: I do not know more about this, I just want to know is there a way to validate the username and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's none. You are trying to check credentials over an inactive remote object (a powered off VM). You will either need access to its local drive and SAM database (if it's a non-DC) or NTDS database (if DC), then parse that one in your active computing resources to check the supplied credentials. This is kind of ripping one's intestines out just to check if your food would digest in there. So, if the target VM is shut down, you need to skip credentials validation, or use domain credentials that are sure to be valid for that particular VM, but are able to be verified on some other resource (the domain's DC).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know that I cannot validate using the remote connection while virtual machines are stopped, I just want to know whether there is any API available to validate virtual machine credential.

Comment: They should have no API for validating this stuff, otherwise your cloud's security is compromised by default.